# Runtime Enhancement of Pojos on Google Appengine with JDO Enhancer

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo, datanucleus

I am using JDO and want to enhance pojos dynamically at runtime on Google Appengine. This [blog](http://brainpicks.wordpress.com/2010/05/04/runtime-enhancement-with-jdo-and-datanucleus/) post mentions some limitations at the end which is making me wonder whether it will work on GAE? Any pointers will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

But do you mean "runtime", or via API ? Because both are covered adequately in the [DataNucleus docs](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_1/enhancer.html). Whether GAE allows you to specify things like javaagent is unknown to me

Comment: I meant at "runtime" i.e. after the application is deployed to GAE. I would like to state here that I was successful in enhancing inmemory created pojos at runtime. The DataNucleus docs were helpful and it has everything which is required to achieve enhancement of pojos at runtime on Google Appengine